# Reading the registry with set and get properties

Tags: c#, registry

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.  I have a class created to get some reg key values and I keep on getting type cast errors.  I pass in the name of the key.  The value of the key is a int.  Which should  also be the return value.

I keep on getting this error

> Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to int

in the following locations:

```
rValue = (string)myKey.GetValue("DebugLog");
&set { DebugLog = getDebugLog(value);}
```

note this in in c#

```
private int DebugLog;

private int getDebugLog(String name)
{
    int rValue;
    myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKey + name, false);
    rValue = (string)myKey.GetValue("DebugLog");
    return rValue;
}

public int debugLog
{
    get { return DebugLog; }
    set { DebugLog = getDebugLog(value);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare rValue as an int but set it as a string.  Try this:

```
rvalue = Int32.Parse((string)myKey.GetValue("DebugLog"));
```

Comment: ok rvalue = Int32.Parse((string)myKey.GetValue("DebugLog")); worked, now I am getting the cannot convert from int to string within the get and set methods.        public int debugLog
        {
            get { return DebugLog; }
            set { DebugLogAutoRoll = getDebugLog(value);}
        }

Comment: You will need to write a set funtion with myKey.GetValue("DebugLog", value.ToString()).  If you like, please Accept this answer.

Answer (score 7):

The registry is irrelevant here - you're casting a value to `string`, and then trying to assign that expression to an `int` variable. It's like this:

```
object x = "hello";
int y = (string) x;
```

That's never going to work. If you want to convert a string to an integer, you need to parse it, e.g. with [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).

If the value in the registry is *actually* an integer though, just cast it to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
rValue = Convert.ToInt32(myKey.GetValue("DebugLog"));
```